# How can I figure out if my power supply is root cause of custom build reboots under load?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I'm working on [this custom PC build](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/). I reused the old case and PSU. Currently I've got things so that they boot Ubuntu 16.04.

I began using this build as a home server up until I started noticing it would power off under any moderate load. To investigate, I found the Linux [stress](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/) tool. I feared the CPU was getting to hot and the BIOS was turning the PC off. I installed lm-sensors to view CPU temp and ran the PC under loads such as `stress -c 8` (8 CPU hogs) and indeed noticed the CPU temp spiking to unhealthy levels ( > 100 deg C). Eventually `stress -c 16 -m 4` (16 CPU hogs, 4 heavy memory alloc/dealloc) caused the power to seemingly cycle. Indeed initially I thought this was the CPU temp.

I just finished installing a new heatsink. In my first couple of runs with `stress` CPU temps indeed seem more sensible and recover much faster after load.

**BUT** once I ran `stress -c 16 -m 4` the power seemed to cycle on the PC. Now I'm wondering if this is somehow either a memory or PSU issue, and I'm trying to figure out how to isolate whether the PSU could be the problem. Otherwise its some kind of short on the motherboard only triggered by something I do in software (seems unlikely)

### Symptoms that make me think its the PSU

- Hitting the front panel power button to power off/on doesn't work.
- Usually I have to wait 5 minutes before a front panel off/on boots and I see the mobo go through its normal boot LEDs
- If I cycle the hardware power on the PSU, suddenly I can boot again
- What I'm doing with `stress` to cause this *seems* to correspond with components drawing ever increasing power
- The PSU is 7 years old
- The power cycle comes with an audible 'click' as if something is actually cycling and not related to something happening in the BIOS

### Why it might not be the PSU

- This PSU worked fine in my really old build, but this build had a beefier video card I don't have here. Though it hasn't done real work in a while.
- It should allow up to 650W, and I shouldn't be coming close to that based on the pc parts picker list above

Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot whether this issue is caused by the PSU? Does this seem like it would be caused by the PSU? If not, what might be causing my symptoms?

Comment: The only reliable tests are parts substitution or a PSU tester. *"It should allow up to 650W"* -- That could be an exaggeration, especially it it's not a name-brand unit. Regardless, the rated power capacity is the sum of the individual voltage rails. Protection circuits should trip if any rail has an issue.

Comment: Consider checking the RAM for faults. If there are none you'd be left with less components. if you hear a click try to get an idea of which component is doing it.